# Getting Error "Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android" while react-native doctor

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting Error "Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android" while react-native doctor

**npx react-native doctor**

```
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ yarn - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ✓ Watchman - Used for watching changes in the filesystem when in development mode

Android
 ✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device.
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 33.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

iOS
 ✓ Xcode - Required for building and installing your app on iOS
 ✓ Ruby - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ✓ CocoaPods - Required for installing iOS dependencies
 ✓ ios-deploy - Required for installing your app on a physical device with the CLI
 ✓ .xcode.env - File to customize Xcode environment

Errors:   2
Warnings: 0

Usage
 › Press f to try to fix issues.
 › Press e to try to fix errors.
 › Press w to try to fix warnings.
 › Press Enter to exit.
```

**npx react-native info**

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
  OS: macOS 14.0
  CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
  Memory: 186.30 MB / 16.00 GB
  Shell:
    version: "5.9"
    path: /bin/zsh
Binaries:
  Node:
    version: 16.13.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/node
  Yarn:
    version: 1.22.19
    path: /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm:
    version: 8.1.0
    path: ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/npm
  Watchman:
    version: 2023.09.04.00
    path: /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
  CocoaPods:
    version: 1.12.1
    path: /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms:
      - DriverKit 23.0
      - iOS 17.0
      - macOS 14.0
      - tvOS 17.0
      - watchOS 10.0
  Android SDK: Not Found
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 2022.3 AI-223.8836.35.2231.10671973
  Xcode:
    version: 15.0/15A240d
    path: /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
  Java:
    version: 11.0.20.1
    path: /usr/bin/javac
  Ruby:
    version: 2.6.10
    path: /usr/bin/ruby
npmPackages:
  "@react-native-community/cli": Not Found
  react:
    installed: 18.2.0
    wanted: 18.2.0
  react-native:
    installed: 0.72.5
    wanted: 0.72.5
  react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  "*react-native*": Not Found
Android:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
iOS:
  hermesEnabled: true
  newArchEnabled: false
```

Comment: Do you have installed android studio and the SDK ?

Comment: I checked and confirmed that it's coming on the new react native version 0.72.5

Comment: Hi, im facing the same error so did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the errors that I'm seeing there, it seems like you need to:

- Install the Android SDK via Android Studio's SDK Manager
- Create an emulator via Android Studio's AVD Manager OR connect an Android device to your computer via USB